# Find Maximum amount of Coins and Selected Coins

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I'm doing Coin Row Problem. And i got a small problem.

There is a row of n coins whose values are some positive integers `c1, c2, . . . , cn`, not necessarily distinct.

The goal is to pick up the maximum amount of money subject to the constraint that you cannot pick up any two adjacent coins.  For instance, in the example below, once you pick up `10`, you cannot take either `6` or the left-hand `2`.

Example:

```
enter the number of coins: 6
enter the value of all coins : 5 1 2 10 6 2 
The maximum amount of coin : 17
The selected coins to get maximum value : C1 , C4 , C6
```

I wanna get Selected coins (C1, C4, C6 in ex).

Here is my function code
I just can get only maximum amount in this code.

```
int getanswer(int array[],int len)
{
  int C[20];
  for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
  {
        C[j + 1] = array[j];
  }

  int F[20];
  F[0] = 0;
  F[1] = C[1];

  for (int j = 2; j < len+1; j++)
  {
      F[j] = max(C[j] + F[j - 2], F[j - 1]);
      printf("temp :%d\n", C[j]);
  }

  return F[len];
}
```

How can i get Selected coins with my code?

Comment: Before "how should I code" you should ask (yourself)  "what would be the algorithm?".

Comment: @EugeneSh. How about "what would be the algorithm and how should I code it?" (I'm quite sure the question could be improved further, though)

Comment: @Swordfish That would be something I would VTC without a comment :)

Comment: What is your question? A proposal how to do this any way, i.e. inefficient brute force is fine? Or do you already have a brute force solution and are asking for optimisation? In the latter case please show the code you have.

Comment: If i don't have enough coins i can't buy cigarettes from the cigarette machine :(

Comment: Before "how should I code" ask yourself "which language should I choose" and select C or C++.  They are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `std::vector` for runtime and `std::string` for text.  The C language doesn't.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, use `std::vector` instead of arrays.  Passing `std::vector` by reference is easier than passing arrays.  When passing arrays, you'll have to pass the capacity as well.

Comment: Hint - a natural solution would be recursive. You will have to check two paths - one taking the next coin, and the other with not taking it. Like Haskell? https://repl.it/repls/SphericalWelllitMining

Comment: Your function has undefined behavior when `num` is passed as negative or greater than 20.

Comment: I think the solution is going to involve looking at every possible combination of coins and deciding which one is best. Unless you are feeling particularly clever, in which case you can try a different approach. So, for now, I'd focus on how to look at every possible combination. @EugeneSh.already hinted at one way.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would involve recursion, backtracking, and memoization (dynamic programming).  Write a recursive routine that tries each of the available choices from the left end, and then recurs on the remaining list.  Your current algorithm has a blind spot for unbalanced values just over its visible horizon (2 elements out).

Here's some pseudo-code to help you start.

```
int pickup(coin[])
{
    // base case: <= 2 coins left
    if size(coin) == 0           // return 0 for an empty list
        return 0
    if size(coin) <= 2           // if only 1 or 2 coins left, return the larger
        return max(coin)

    // Otherwise, experiment:
    //   pick *each* of the first two coins, solve the remaining problem,
    //   and compare results.
    pick1 = coin[0] + pickup(coin[2:])      // pick 1st coin; recur on rest of list
    pick2 = coin[1] + pickup(coin[3:])      // pick 2nd coin; recur on rest of list

    return max(pick1, pick2)
```

That's the general attack.  You can speed up the solution a *lot* with memoization.  Also, you'll need to convert this to your preferred implementation language *and* add tracking to this so you get the indices you want.  If all you need is to return the coin values in order, it's a simple to accumulate an array of those values, pre-pending one on each return.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer :) 

But how can i get 'selected coins(like C1, C4, C6)' in your algorithm??

Comment: As I said, you need to accumulate those values on return from each recursive call.

Comment: Thank you so much. Kind bro :)